# Deploy Excel Workbook Project from VS2010

Tags: c#, activex, vsto, ms-office, excel-2007

I have created my first Excel 2007 workbook project in C# using VS2010 that contains a few buttons and carries out a bunch of tasks that all seems to work quite well. I now need it to run on users' machines but I'm not quite sure how to get it to work as the workbook loads but the buttons are inactive and the code doesn't run. I would presume the machine will need the VSTO run-time 3.0 installed, but what else is required?

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I published as a ClickOnce application.